# Is it possible to send messages to Telegram's "Saved Messages" through the API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-api

Is it possible to send a message via **Telegram API** to the **Saved Messages** chat?

I have been looking all over the internet but could not find any information. I would think this would be possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the main mtproto api, yes you can send yourself a message by your id or username and telegram will place it in saved messages.

You did not mention which API you use, but this is how you do it in Telethon:

```py
client.send_message("me", "hello")
```

But if you mean bot api, it's not possible for bots to send messages to your saved message.

Comment: Cool, I use the API directly, is it possible to do with the API directly?

Comment: @Keff which api do you use?

Comment: The telegram HTTP API directly. https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api

Comment: @Keff Which language and library?

Comment: node js, with no library, directly through the HTTP API

Comment: @Keff Well then you're using [BOT API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/), the link you gave is MTPROTO Api and that's not built on http. The thing you want to do is not possible with bots.

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thank you! I will investigate a bit more with the info you gave me!